# AndEngine game crashing just after opening for a moment

Tags: android, andengine

I was just testing a game (actually it's just a splash screen now) with the help of AndEngine and when testing it <strike>on CyanogenMod (unofficial)</strike> it just loads for a millisecond, and closes. What is the error?

- I have overridden `onDestroy()` to add `System.exit(0);`.
- I have extended `BaseGameActivity`.
- The part running as from class `MainActivity`:

  ```
  protected final int width = 640, height = 480;
  public Camera camera;

  @Override
  public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
      camera = new Camera(0, 0, width, height);
      EngineOptions EO = new EngineOptions(true,
              ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
              new RatioResolutionPolicy(width, height), camera);
      return EO;
  }
  ```

Log:

```
E/Trace(2677): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
D/AndEngine(2677): MainActivity.onCreate @(Thread: 'main')    
D/dalvikvm(2677): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.package/lib/libandengine.so 0x40dbb400
D/dalvikvm(2677): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.package/lib/libandengine.so 0x40dbb400
D/dalvikvm(2677): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.package/lib/libandengine.so 0x40dbb400, skipping init
D/AndEngine(2677): MainActivity.onResume @(Thread: 'main')
D/AndEngine(2677): MainActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')
D/AndEngine(2677): MainActivity.onDestroy @(Thread: 'main')
D/AndEngine(2677): UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this EngineDestroyedException is most likely expected!
D/AndEngine(2677): org.andengine.engine.Engine$EngineDestroyedException
D/AndEngine(2677):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.throwOnDestroyed(Engine.java:574)
D/AndEngine(2677):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:560)
D/AndEngine(2677):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
D/AndEngine(2677): MainActivity.onDestroyResources @(Thread: 'main')
D/AndEngine(2677): MainActivity.onGameDestroyed @(Thread: 'main')
I/AndroidRuntime(2677): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
```

Comment: from the info you've provided everything seems to be ok - activity is started and finished successfully. don't pay attention to andengine exception - it is ok

Comment: i also attached two sprites and a TimerHandler for 10s. the sprite are also having alpha modifiers.

Comment: that's not the case. your activity is been created and finished ok. you are calling `finish()` somewhere in your code, I guess

Comment: Sorry but I haven't called `finish()` anywhere ... Thnx .. Now I have just edited my another existing app's copy to this and it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I opened the app again and again it opened one of the few times and after I mentioned this in manifest it opened always:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Don't know why but this is a problem with andengine if you forgot to mention this.